# Clients' Policy Violations Risk for App Store & Google Play

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a developer account and have some apps. I'm considering working as a freelancer now. I could have more than 10 clients in a year. If I upload my clients' apps to their developer accounts using my MacBook, and if one of them violate policies in their other apps and their developer accounts are suspended, will my personal developer account be affected negatively?

(Because my macbook will be used for app submission, May Apple or Google relate my personal developer account with them?)

Comment: Reminder StackOverflow is for programming/technical related questions. This question appears to fall under [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/295004) and/or [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004) You'll probably have better luck on an appropriate forum on a social discussion site like reddit or discord.

Comment: Yes you are right but I think developers answer this question perfectly as probably they have experience about this situation.